# Org ASCII export with indentation preserved

Tags: org-export, indentation

Open your EMACS `-Q`, enter org mode, and

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp

  (setf x '(a b c
              d e f))

#+end_src
```

This is how it will be aligned after `org-edit-special` (`C-c '`).

Now export to an ASCII buffer with `C-c C-e t A`.   You will see

```
,----
| 
| (setf x '(a b c
|           d e f))
| 
`----
```

Clearly, the indentation has changed.  How does one get
indentation as in the source?

---

P.S.

This does not happen when exporting to a LaTeX buffer.  It seems
to be a bug resulting from the use of tab characters and the
insertion of two extra characters at the beginning of each source
line.  I suppose plain-text export isn't used that much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just see to it that the whole buffer is free of tabulators
before you export it.  To avoid untabbing the original,
use a hook.

```
    (defun org*-export-untabify (backend)
      (untabify 0 (point-max)))

    (add-hook 'org-export-before-parsing-hook 'org*-export-untabify)
```